# How to change color in a specific time in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change color in a specific time in CSS?
For example, I want to change paragraph color in a specific time.

```
<style>
    p {
     color: black;
}
</style>
<p>I want to be white!</p>
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I mean 1 second for example for this sentence

> in a specific time

Comment: Do you mean with CSS + JavaScript ?

Comment: "in a specific time" as in 12:40 on January 5th, or as when a user does something or some condition(s) is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `animation`

```css
 p {
   color: black;
   animation:animate .1s linear forwards;
   animation-delay:5s; /* text will be red after 5 second */
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {color:red}
}
```

```html
<p>I want to be red!</p>
```